# Monitor resolution isn't selectable

Tags: resolution, display, monitor

I've got a 2560x1440 monitor, connected with a dual-link DVI cable. When I boot into Ubuntu 13.04, the resolution is 1600X1200 by default, and in Systems Settings->Displays, the highest resolution listed is 1920x1080. How can I select the actual full resolution of 2560x1440? I've got Integrated Intel HD 4000 Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this with one of my dual monitors, the issue that I had was that the drivers weren't installed properly and up to date. Maybe that is the issue?

I would comment, but I can't until I get 50 rep :*(

Comment: To make this an Answer, could you add more information so that the person asking the question has a few steps to follow to fix their problem.